# I have a jQuery function that alters titles in Wordpress and I tried to add a link to the title and it's not behaving right

Tags: jquery, wordpress, loops, hyperlink, title

Here's the function:

```
$('.entry-title').each(function() {
    var dotdotdot = $(this).html().indexOf('…'); 
    $(this).html('<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span class="category">' + $(this).html().substring(0, dotdotdot) + '</span>' + $(this).html().substring(dotdotdot) + '</a>');
});
```

The original intent was to add a span tag into the text of the title itself and that worked beautifully (thanks @making3). The code `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>` `+ '</a>'`is what I later added to the original function.

What I am trying to do is wrap a link around the title so it will link to the single post page. The screwy part is these titles are looping through each post on the page backwards and creating multiple empty links for every post. Only the last link has the title in it, but it's not the correct link for that title. So clearly what I did is totally wrong.

Here's my markup:

```
<article <?php post_class(); ?>>
<script>
$('.entry-title').each(function() {
    var dotdotdot = $(this).html().indexOf('…'); 
    $(this).html('<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span class="category">' +     $(this).html().substring(0, dotdotdot) + '</span>' + $(this).html().substring(dotdotdot) + '</a>');
});
</script>
  <header>
    <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
  </header>
  <div class="entry-summary">
    <div class="entry">
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: markup added @tushar-gupta

Comment: I solved it. I took the link out of the jQuery function, added a class to to that and then called the link class name in the function. Now it all works. `$('.permalink').each(function() { var dotdotdot = $(this).html().indexOf('…'); $(this).html('<span class="category">' + $(this).html().substring(0, dotdotdot) + '</span>' + $(this).html().substring(dotdotdot));});` Then: `<header><h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="permalink"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></header>`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you've modified your jQuery code as follows:

```
<script>
$('.permalink').each(function() {
    var dotdotdot = $(this).html().indexOf('…'); 
    $(this).html('<span class="category">' + $(this).html().substring(0, dotdotdot) + '</span>' + $(this).html().substring(dotdotdot));
});
</script>
```

I'm sure this looks fine on the page but behind the scenes you are outputting that jQuery code for each post and since it does a .each function it operates on every post in each instance of the code so that results in multiple nested span tags.

Right now your HTML is getting rendered as the following through jQuery:

```
<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="/crushing-on/crushing-on-making-a-change/" class="permalink"><span class="category"><span class="category"><span class="category"><span class="category"><span class="category"><span class="category">Crushing on</span></span></span></span></span></span>…making a change</a></h2>
```

(right click an element in chrome and click inspect element to see this for yourself)

This is happening because of the multiple instances of the jQuery code when you only want once instance to operate on all the links.  To fix this put this jQuery code block at the top of the page outside the PHP loop that is generating the posts so it only gets output once.